# How to use GrammarRules and GrammarApply with different languages?

Tags: string-manipulation, wolfram-cloud

I want to use PLI with GrammarToken/GrammarRules/GrammarApply in Russian language. But it doesn't work

```
grammar = CloudDeploy[GrammarRules["Привет" -> "Здравствуй"]]; 
GrammarApply[grammar, "Привет"]

(* Out[..] := $Failed *)
```

Comment: This is not the way `Grammar` is meant by WRI. It is a different concept to `Language`. Classify["Language", {"Привет"}] gives {Entity["Language", "Russian"]}, analog for "Hi". TextTranslation["Привет"] gives "Hello". TextTranslation has the option target language. Language is different from grammar. I. e. `TextTranslation["Grammar","Russian]` gives Грамматики. Introduce for example with [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar] yourself. Then look at [http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ProgrammableLinguisticInterface.html] for the Grammar construction primitives Mathematica offers.

Comment: @user2432923 I do not understand what you mean. I do not want to do a translator, I want to process Russian. Or do you think that only English can be processed?